# Cold Boot: Snapshot doesn't exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Anytime I try to run my app, the emulator is just a blackscreen and a notification saying "Cold boot: Snapshot doesn't exist". I'm sure this is a simple fix but I am new to Android Studio. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. First, delete the device from Tool>AVD manager. Then install a new device (API 25 or 26) which supports Google Play Store feature. After installing the device, there is a notification which asks you to update the Google Play store. Updating the Google Play store solves the problem. I hope this method helps you.